# How to access to a value in an array by index or by value?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a project which have this kind of of code :

```
<?php
$dbsecteurs = dbselect("SELECT * FROM SUP_SECTEURS WHERE ID_SECTEUR > 1 ORDER BY NOM_SECTEUR ASC");
    foreach ($dbsecteurs as $dbsecteur) {
        echo $dbsecteur[0];
    }
}
?>
```

So the lines are readed by the index. Sometimes, values are accessed like that `$dbsecteur['id']`. I have to update the PHP's version. This was the dbselect function :

```
function dbselect($strquery) {
    global $diag;
    $linkID = dbconnect("NORMAL");
    if($diag==1) {
        echo($strquery."<br>");
    }
    $result= oci_parse($linkID,$strquery);
}
```

I don't know why but I have this error `PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\surtemps_dev\admin\login.php on line 147`. So I changed the function's code to this :

```
function dbselect($strquery) {
    global $diag;
    $linkID = dbconnect("NORMAL");
    if($diag==1) {
        echo($strquery."<br>");
    }
    $stdid = oci_parse($linkID,$strquery);
    oci_execute($stdid);
    oci_fetch_all($stdid, $result, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW+OCI_NUM);
    return $result;
}
```

It works for values accessed by index but not by key. I can access by key if I remove the `OCI_NUM` but I can't access to both.

Is there a way to access to the same array by key and by index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. This is the new function :

```
function dbselect($strquery) {
    global $diag;
    $linkID = dbconnect("NORMAL");
    if($diag==1) {
        echo($strquery."<br>");
    }
    $result = oci_parse($linkID,$strquery);
    oci_execute($result,OCI_DEFAULT);

    $matrix=array();
    $i=0;
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($matrix,array());
        $matrix[$i]=$row;
        $i++;
    }

    dbclose($linkID);

    return $matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
return $result;
```

Change that line to:

```
return array_merge($result,array_values($result));
```

Comment: First change `OCI_NUM` to `OCI_ASSOC`.

Comment: I tried those solutions but I have the same result. I can access to the array by value or by index but not both.